# jQuery - Slide an element to the left and change its style

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have a simple div with images and text in it. Also I have a link `.remove` and I want to animate it to slide to the left and change it's background, text and so on.

So far I've done this. But there's a little bug (check it when you hover fast several times it).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.remove').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '85px'
        });
    },

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '11px'
        })
    });
});
```

Here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/9jQtt/

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is if you hover in and out quickly, the animations just stack up.  You need to cancel the previous animation by calling `.stop()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').hover(function(e){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '85px'});
    },
    function(e){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '11px'})
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9jQtt/1/

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty common when using jQuery's .animate() function that it is triggered by a mouseEnter or hover event. The standard way to deal with this is using the .stop() function, like:

```
$(this).stop().animate({ width: "85px" });
```

But you may want to try something different too which is explained here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Actually, using stop() stops the animation without getting complete. Depending on your case or if you want, you can let the animation complete and disable queueing. It is explained in the above link.

Answer (score 3):

Though I love me some jQuery, you should consider just using the [CSS3 transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) (for browsers that support them) and letting older browsers have the non-animated transitions.

A working, CSS3 edit of your [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9jQtt/5/), with the pertinent css:

```
.author .remove:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width:80px;
}
```