# jQuery .toggleClass() speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery *.toggleClass()* function, class will toggled per click, that works perfectly, but i can't setup speed, i have tried this:

```
$('#databox').toggleClass('boxopened', 7000);
```

also this:

```
$('#databox').toggleClass('boxopened', 'easeInQuad');
```

and also this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hover-and-toggleclass-fail-at-speed

I have add latest **jquery 1.10** and **jqueryUI: 1.10.3**

It's possible to setup speed?

Comment: Checked [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for you. `.toggleClass` does not support speed - you need `.animate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you are including JQuery UI Effects - the base JQuery does not allow transitions on show/hide/toggle, it's added as an extension from UI Effects. (In your app, or in browser console, try `running $.ui.version`)

http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

EDIT:Works for me on `$.ui.version => "1.10.3"` (the version you requested). Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yKFjA/1/

What styling changes are being applied that you wish to see animated?

Comment: if i try to use: console.log ($.ui); - as output i see: undefined
and this console.log ($.ui.version); as out i see: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

Comment: Meaning you don't have JQuery UI loaded. You only have JQuery (base) right now. Once you get JQuery UI in there things should work.

Comment: Answer on: What styling changes are being applied that you wish to see animated? - that's request, if box is heigher then 207px, then height is 207 with overflow hidden, and if i click on the button, then i add new class who has: height: auto;

Comment: Yeah, that should work, just try reconfiguring things to make sure the JQuery UI library is loaded. It isn't being fetched (otherwise $.ui wouldn't be undefined).

Comment: now works perfectly, .css file must be includes before .js file, thanks to all... it was hard experience :)

Answer (score 6):

Add to your classes:

**CSS**:

```
    -webkit-transition:0.4s;
    -moz-transition:0.4s;
    -ms-transition:0.4s;
    -o-transition:0.4s;
    transition:0.4s;
```

This "transition declaration" will force the timer , if its not working try adding `!important`
or give us some code to inspect.

**HERE IS A DEMO:**

[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/617/jQuery-toggleClass-speed)

Comment: Excellent suggestion if you are not using jQuery UI.

Comment: the JSnippet Demo is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting the speed via CSS3 transitions; the [answer I gave to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415377/jquery-slide-an-element-to-the-left-and-change-its-style/17415828#17415828) can get you started if that interests you. @Shlomi Hassid also provides similar advice.

This has some advantages

- simplification of code,
- separation of concerns,
- possibly better performance by handing off the job to the browser,
- definitely better performance on older browsers

and disadvantages -- inconsistent browser implementations mean anywhere from slight differences to non-functional (on older browsers, though I think the performance benefit outweighs the consistency benefit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#databox').toggleClass('boxopened', 1000, 'easeInQuad');
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to delay the change in class, use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout( function(){

$('#databox').toggleClass('boxopened');

}, 7000 };
```