# How to Use jquery Animate() with .slideToggle() Between Two Classes

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to add some smoothness( Animation) to changing a div width by using this method

```
$("#changer").on("click",function(){
  $("#thediv").toggleClass("w-2 w-1");
});
```

CSS:

```
.w-1{height :200px witdh: 200px;}
.w-2{height :200px witdh: 300px;}
```

As you know I can toggle the classes but changing the size is happening very fast and causing like skipping all element at once. Now I need to use some efets like CSS3 or jQyery animation to toggling the classes smoothly. Can you pleae let me know how to do that?

I already tried this:

```
$("#changer").on("click",function(){
  $("#thediv").toggleClass(1000, "col-md-2 col-md-1");
});
```

to add some speed but it didn't woek

Comment: Add transition: height 1s width 1s;  to the element style

Comment: Without jQuery Ui effects you cannot have a speed on a toggle - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837236/jquery-toggleclass-speed

Comment: @vals, thanks for reply I add the Add transition: height 1s width 1s; to .w-1{height 1s width 1s;} and .w-2{height 1s width 1s;} but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, make sure you are using jquery UI and then use toggleClass with speed. 
Remember the first param is the class name and second param is speed so try this

```
$("#thediv").toggleClass("col-md-2 col-md-1", 1000);
```

instead of this -

```
$("#thediv").toggleClass(1000, "col-md-2 col-md-1");
```

Aksom see this exmaple -- http://jsfiddle.net/yKFjA/1/

Answer (score 0):

> Without jQuery Ui effects you cannot have a speed on a toggle  -- As Jay said; 
>   but you can do this ->

```
$("#changer").on("click",function(){
     $("#thediv").hide();
     $("#thediv").toggleClass("w-2 w-1");
     $('#thediv').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Hope this helps!